# many onClick are executed

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

My code looks as follow:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="west"   resizable="false" collapsible="true"   style="color: #ccc;padding-left: 50px;border-right-color: yellowgreen;border-left: none;border-bottom: none;border-top-color: yellowgreen;"  >
   <h:link  value="Sport" styleClass="link" outcome="products" onclick="#{acount.rechercherLivreByTheme('Sport')}">
       <f:param name="nom" value="Art" />
   </h:link><br/>
   <h:link  value="Informatique" styleClass="link" outcome="products" onclick="#{acount.rechercherLivreByTheme('Informatique')}">
       <f:param name="nom" value="Informatique" />
   </h:link><br/>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

The **problem** is that when I click in one link the 2 methods are executed like if I had clicked in the two links.

**Edit**

What I have discovered from reviewing my full code is thah all my onClick are executed , I have issue with putting the form tag in the good place

How can we use the form tag if we have many button,with many layouts?

Comment: The method expression should **not** be placed in an `onclick`. Use a `commandLink` instead, and place your method expression in the `action` attribute of the commandLink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` is for JavaScript code that will be executed onclick. Therefore, JSF need to render the content of this attribute before sending it to the browser (so all EL code is executed at render). This is not an event that will be generated server side.

You are probably looking for `action` or `actionListener` both available with other JSF components like `h:commandLink` for instance.